# HTACCESS: Redirect all the requests to another page, in place of index, hiding arguments?

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

I expose here my issue, I hope to explain myself clearly and correctly. In case of any specification, please ask me.

What I need is to redirect all the request (except the one to index.php) to another .php file, without the necessity to specify an argument.

here an example of what I need to do:

```
http://www.example.com -> shows index.php
```

but:

`http://www.example.com/songs/title-of-the-song`

should call the page: songs.php?dir=title-of-the-song of course without showin to the user the string "songs.php?dir=title-of-the-song" but just the URL

`http://www.example.com/songs/title-of-the-song`

It's what occurs with Drupal, but i'm not using that CMS for my site.

Comment: This has been answered about 4538365482 times alone here on SO. All those answers, which you hopefully took a look at, did not help you? Why not? Don't get this wrong, not trying to be picky here. But you should always _first_ try to succeed yourself. Only if you run into a problem, _then_ is the time to ask a question about _that specific problem_ you cannot solve yourself.

Comment: It's what I did arkascha. Perhaps all the 4538365482 were unclear to me. And all what I tried, it was unsuccessful, because unclear and lead me to small but significant mistakes.
Perhaps before to think the other ones "are not trying", try to rephrase your thoughts into "perhaps the other ones tried, read the doc, but for any reason they didn't succeed" ... if I post something, it's because I don't find the solution that for me works as it should, even trying and re-trying. Indeed, once you gave me the help, I also got a malfunction, that I solved experimenting and getting rid of the "/".

Comment: Sorry if I frustrated you, that certainly was not my intention. It appears you got the message of that comment I made in a negative way. Sorry again, but that is not my fault. I clearly stated what the issue with the question is: you ask something that _has_ been answered many many times. _Now_ you  claim that none of the answers solved you problem. But you completely fail to post in your question, why all those examples did not help. That is why I asked: "that specific problem"... If you knew about the information from all those questions, then what on top did you ask? I failed to spot that..

Comment: I still do not understand why now, with my answer below, you succeeded, whilst with all the other answers you claim their content did not help you. But actually my answer contains nothing new compare to those answers.

Comment: Because all the answers I read before to post this thread, didn't clarified me how to manage the lines/instructions.
Your very simple but effective answer, cleared me out everything and I was able to do what i designed to do. Then, thanks to your help, I was able also to complete the HTACESS with some other instruction I needed. And finally things are working as they should, like avoiding that directories are exploitable except for specific content etc. (avoiding to put an empty index.html or .php, etc.

Comment: Sure, the answers here on stackoverflow are not meant to teach you how to use things like rewriting rules in the configuration of your http server. That is what the documentation is for, maybe one of the many "getting started" guides helps too. Of course I assume you did read the documentation when you came to a point where you were confused about the commands. That is how SO works which is what I said.

Comment: Anyways, this is all irrelevant. I am glad I could help, great that you sorted out your issue. And since SO is a place to give and take, now it is also up to give to give something back :-) Welcome to the team!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/songs/(.+)$ /songs.php?dir=$1 [L]
```

Note: this is the version for the http host configuration. For usage in `.htaccess` style files you have to adapt it slightly. But if you have access to the host configuration you should always prefer that over `.htaccess` style files. Those files require an additional module, are notoriously error prone, hard to troubleshoot and really slow the server down.

Comment: I thank you really very much, it worked out.
I had to make a small modification:

    RewriteRule  ^songs/(.+)$ songs.php?dir=$1 [L]

Perhaps it is because the songs.php is in the root ... however no wit works greatly :)

Comment: @TormyVanCool "this is the version for the http host configuration" - that is why you had to make a small modification. In per-directory .htaccess files the directory prefix (`/`) is removed from the URL-path before the pattern is matched.